# Lua nonsense to find if something is nil

Tags: lua

There seems to be a difference between these two checks:

`if not object then`

`if type(object) == "nil" then`

However I really don't understand the difference.
if type is "nil", shouldn't a `not object` then also work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lua, like many other dynamically typed languages, has the concept of "truthy" and "falsy", where boolean expressions can handle more values than just actual booleans.

Each non-boolean value has a specific meaning attached when used in a boolean expression. Specifically:

- `nil` and `false` are "falsy"
- everything else is "truthy"

That is why `(not nil) == (not false)`, but `type(nil) ~= type(false)`, because `not x` is a boolean expression that coerces `x` to truthy/falsy, while `type()` checks the actual type.

Comment: I'm sorry but I still don't get it.
If object is nil or false, then `not object` should work, right?
Since `type(object) == nil` that means it's definitely nil, right? So why wouldn't `not object` work then? I'm horribly confused, hah. sorry..

Comment: @Snoogens it would work. If `type(object) == "nil"` is true, then `not object` is also true

Comment: @user253751 strangely enough the code breaks if we don't use `type(object) == "nil"`, hah..

Comment: @Snoogens perhaps because `not object` is also true when `object` is `false`. `type(object) == "nil"` is equivalent to `object == nil` however

Comment: We will have to know more about your code (ideally an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) to figure out why `not object` breaks for you.